# Spring Form Tags set autocapitalize="off"

Tags: spring, input

I am using the taglib `http://www.springframework.org/tags/form` and i got a input field which is created by the following way.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<form:input cssClass="${inputCSS}" id="email" placeholder="${placeHolder}"/>
```

The problem is now that many mobiledevices automatically capitalize the first letter. I know that i can prevent this in normal html by setting `autocapitalize="off"`.

Is there any way except javaScript (which I don't want to use if theres an other way) to set `autocapitalize="off"`for jstl forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamic attributes are supported in spring form tag since Spring 3.1. Use like this:

```
<form:input cssClass="${inputCSS}" id="email" placeholder="${placeHolder}" autocapitalize="off"/>
```

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-html5